# browse a JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have JSON value on my database. This JSON has objets which are which are defined with number. This is my object :

```
<pre> 
object(stdClass)#8 (4) {
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#7 (3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "CHANTAL HARNOIS"
    ["content"]=>
    string(291) "Retraitée de 63 ans : 'J'ai eu envie de créer cette association après une discussion avec mon pneumologue qui m'a mise en relation avec 2 autres asthmatiques sévères. L'élan est venu de cette rencontre, nous voulions faire reconnaître l'asthme sévère et aider ceux qui en souffrait'"
    ["subtitle"]=>
    string(45) "Co fondatrice et Présidente de l'association"
  }
}
</pre>
```

When I try to browse my object with PHP, I use `json_decode()` like this :

```
<?php
    $txt = json_decode($temoignages->getOne($pdo, 1)['content']);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($txt->**1**->name)
?>
```

It doesn't work because my object have number (1,2,3)...  I tried putting letters in place and it works, but I absolutely have to put integers

Someone can help me ? please..

Comment: That is not a JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `json_decode` with `true` as second parameter. This way you will have an array and you could get your data with `$txt['1'][...]`.

```
<?php
    $txt = json_decode($temoignages->getOne($pdo, 1)['content'], true);

    echo "<pre>";
    echo var_dump($txt['1']['name'])
?>
```

Comment: yes, thank you it's works